# Bounds for intervals of log-concave distributions.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a proof regarding log-cocave Distributions right now. The following statement looks right to me and it feels like the proof should be easy but I just don't see it.
Can you tell me if it's true and provide proof if possible? Thank you!

Let $\alpha$ be a log-concave distribution, which means that $\alpha(x) = \exp(-f(x))$ with convex $f$,  $t > 0$ and $0 <\lambda<1 $. If $\alpha(x_0+t) < \lambda \alpha(x_0)$, is it true that $\alpha(x_0 + rt) < \lambda^r\alpha(x_0)$ for all real $r > 1$ ?

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ is convex, and not log-concave instead?

Comment: @bodil Yes, you're right, thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\alpha(x) = \exp(-f(x))$ with a convex function $f$. So it is given that
$$ \tag 1
 f(x_0 + t) > f(x_0) + \ln \lambda
$$
and the goal is to show that
$$ \tag 2
 f(x_0 + rt) > f(x_0) + r \ln \lambda \, .
$$

This follows directly from the convexity condition  for $x_0 < x_0 + t < x_0 + r t$:
$$
 f(x_0+t) \le \frac{r - 1}{r} f(x_0)+ \frac{1}{r} f(x_0+rt) \, .
$$

Using $(1)$ we can estimate the left-hand side:
$$
 f(x_0) + \ln \lambda \le \frac{r - 1}{r} f(x_0)+ \frac{1}{r} f(x_0+rt) \, .
$$
and that simplifies to $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!